# White patches with black dots on leaves of Areca Palm

Tags: plant-care, leaves, palm

I have a small Areca Palm and today I noticed these small white patches appearing on the leaves, the patch is on the top and bottom side of the leaf, it almost looks like it's dried out? Whatever it is it looks like I've spotted it early as for the most part the plant still looks nice and healthy but I was hoping someone could tell me if these patches are something I should be concerned about?

Thanks very much!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

They look Yellowish to me. Yellow spots on plants are indicative of magnesium deficiency.
One way is to dissolve Epsom salt (magnesium sulfate) in hot water (1 tablespoon per gallon of water). Palms frequently suffer from improper mineral nutrition in the landscape. The most common nutritional deficiencies of palms are nitrogen (N), potassium (K), magnesium (Mg) and manganese (Mn). It may not save the leaves but the new growth will replace it. Use a fertilizer recommended for palm trees

1. Sunniland Palm Granules Organic All Purpose
2. PalmGain 8-2-12 palm feed with instructions on the label.